# Parabola with three normals from a given point.

Tags: conic-sections

we know that the equation of normal at $(am^2,-2am)$ is $y=mx-2am-am^3.$ If it passes through the point $(h,k)$  then..
$$am^3+0m^2+m(2a-h)+k=0  \tag1$$

above is a cubic equation in $m$ with three values of $m.$ Hence from point $(h,k)$ three normals can be drawn who slopes are given by [1].

also 
$m_1+m_2+m_3=\frac{0}{a}=0 $

what's the reason for the sum of the slopes of these normals is zero????

Comment: you already know the reason ..you've written it

Comment: Do you know what is the $0$ in $0\over a$?

Comment: This is an equation in m of degree 3, which has at most 3 real roots in m. therefore there are at most 3 normals concurrent at (h,k).